# Prevent a promise from triggering a global 'unhandled rejection' event

Tags: javascript, promise

I'm writing a library. At one point I create a promise and then swoop in later to add `then/catch` handlers to it. It's possible the promise could fail before I've actually attached an error handler to it. This is fine with me; the promise can exist in a schrödingers-cat-like state until I later maybe decide to look at it.

The problem is, certain environments trigger a global event if *any* promise gets rejected while it has no error handler. Maybe one of my users has done something drastic like [this](https://github.com/sindresorhus/loud-rejection) in Node:

```
process.on('unhandledRejection', function(reason){
    console.error('oops', reason);
    process.exit(1);
});
```

I don't want my rejected promise to trigger that if I know I'm going to go and check its result later.

Is there some official way I can mark a promise to exclude it from any global 'unhandled rejection' event, or do I really have to synchronously attach an error handler to every promise to avoid this?

Comment: Not all environments do this, and the ones that do are wrong IMHO. As long as you hold a reference to the promise somewhere, the environment has no business throwing a fit.

Comment: Right but I can't just ignore reality if I want my library to work in Node. And reality aside, there are valid reasons for an app to want to noisily exit if a rejected promise goes uncaught, for avoiding elusive bugs, so there's got to be a way for a library author to opt out their internal promises from this

Comment: No arguing with reality, however on the second part, I believe Firefox does the right thing: It yells about rejected uncaught promises only if they're no longer referenced. The only downside of this is that this reporting currently takes a few seconds (likely timing out with garbage collection), but I believe they're working on it.

Comment: Ah that does sound like a good way of doing it

Comment: Although technically it would miss a few cases where a promise is still in kept in scope somewhere, but due to some bug in your code you fail to add a catch handler. In which case you have the error-swallowing problem that 'uncaughtRejection' events are intended to solve. Anyway, the reality of Node's behaviour, even if they change it in a future version, means library authors must assume that an uncaught rejection may crash someone's app, regardless of whether we think that's a good thing. So I guess we just have to work around it, and never let a tick end with an unhandled promise existing

Comment: What you're doing doesn't really make sense from an abstract perspective. It's like you're running a piece of synchronous code that might throw, and only surrounding it with a try{}catch{} afterwards. What's preventing you from being able to handle the rejection in advance?

Comment: Just curious, what's your exact use case where you create promises before the handler?

Answer (score 2):

File a bug on the environment (Node). The environment has no business acting on it in a way that's observable to the script.

In Firefox and Chrome there are no script-observable consequences AFAIK.

Even though Chrome will initally flag this as an "unhandled promise rejection" in the console, with an ✖ symbol, and calling it an error, it backs off later if the promise is subsequently handled, changing the ✖ to a ✓, and changing its language to "1 handled promise rejection".

Firefox will only complain if an unhandled promise rejection is garbage collected.

A workaround might be to add a `hold` function, something like:

```
var hold = p => (p.catch(() => {}), p);
```

Then use it to silence Node whenever you know you'll get to a promise later:

```js
var console = { log: msg => div.innerHTML += msg + "<br>" };
window.onerror = () => console.log("window onerror fired");
var wait = ms => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));

var hold = p => (p.catch(() => {}), p);

var p = hold(Promise.reject(new Error("failure")));

wait(2000).then(() => p).catch(e => console.log(e.message + " handled."));
```

```html
<div id="div"></div>
```

Comment: The `hold` idea is great! Super simple, achieves what we want here.  Cool!